# Trouble passing a MySQL connection as a parameter with MethodBase.Invoke C# .NET

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, system.reflection

I have made certain that all three versions of MySQL (from NuGet) are the same. I have one executable and two libraries. I have the executable 'botLoader', library 'botLoaderAPI', and 'logBot'. I have a method that sets some bot data along with passes a MySQL connection so it can store things.

logBot:

```
namespace logBot 
{
    class Bot : IBot
    {
        private MySqlConnection _sqlconn;

        public string RaiseBot(MySqlConnection connToBeUsed, string[] configurationDetails)
        {
            _sqlconn = connToBeUsed;
            /* rest of the code, but the above is the only mention of it for this method */
        }
    }
}
```

botLoaderAPI:

```
namespace botLoaderAPI
{
    public class BotHolder
    {
        private Type _type;
        private Object _instance;
        private MethodInfo _raiseBotMethod;

        public void _setTypeAndMethods(Type type)
        {
            _type = type;
            _instance = Activator.CreateInstance(_type);
            _raiseBotMethod = _type.GetMethod("RaiseBot");
        }

        public string RaiseBot(MySqlConnection conn, string[] configDetails)
        {
            return _raiseBotMethod.Invoke(_instance, new Object[2] { conn, _configDetails}).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the botLoader and pass a MySQL Connection (confirmed it works), I get the following exception:

```
-       InnerException  {"Object of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection' cannot be converted to type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection'."}   System.Exception {System.ArgumentException}
```